# Display IP address in WPF MainWindow.xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

How can I display my Ip address on MainWindow.xaml?( I have a console application that can display IP address. How can I combine the console application with the XAML file? Need some guidance here and advice. Thanks!

XAML file:

```
<Window x:Class="DisplayIP.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DisplayIP"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="Display IP Address" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition/>
    <RowDefinition/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

C# Code for the console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        NetworkInterface[] IF = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

        foreach (NetworkInterface Interface in IF)
        {
            if (Interface.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Loopback) continue;

            Console.WriteLine(" ");
            Console.WriteLine(Interface.Description);


            UnicastIPAddressInformationCollection UnicastIPInfoCol = Interface.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses;
            foreach (UnicastIPAddressInformation UnicatIPInfo in UnicastIPInfoCol)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The IP address is:{0}", UnicatIPInfo.Address);
                Console.WriteLine("The Sub net is:{0}", UnicatIPInfo.IPv4Mask);
            }

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
        }


    }
```

Comment: First step, read a WPF tutorial.

Comment: What do you mean with "combine" ? you want to keep two different applications or you want to take the code from the console application and put it in the WPF one ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally you would like to have all "business logic" in your case the piece of code which gets the IP address in a separate method (or even class). Your console application should only be communicating with the user, and so is your WPF application.

So, you will have 2 "front-end" applications (WPF and Console) which a user can use to get the business logic from a back-end piece of code (method, class, namespace or in bigger applications - library).

So if I were you, I would have created a class (e.g. NetworkInfo) where a method(s) would return the information about the address and the mask (focus on the word return here - the method will return data to the caller, and not print it on the console). Then both applications - the console one and the WPF one will call this method from this class, to get the needed data and present it accordingly - one on the console with Console.WriteLine, and the other one in a Form or a Control with the XAML file.